# Tkinter Python 3 scaling issue on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, scaling

I am maintaining an application in Python3/Tkinter and add an issue opened by my first user on MacOS.
This is the main screen on Windows in 1080p (Linux shows similar result) :

[image]

On MacOS in 2560 x 1600, everything in the UI is scaled approximatively with a 2x size :

[image]

The original code is that one :

```
self.window = Tk.Tk()
self.window.resizable(False,False)
if platform.system() == 'Windows' :
   self.window.iconbitmap('bestarcade.ico')
self.window.title(title)
```

I tried enforcing resolution :

```
self.scriptDir = scriptDir
self.window = Tk.Tk()
self.window.geometry("930x950")
self.window.resizable(False,False)
```

It makes things worse, the application window in MacOS is just cut a little more short

I tried scaling :

```
self.scriptDir = scriptDir
self.window = Tk.Tk()
self.window.tk.call('tk','scaling',0.5)
self.window.resizable(False,False)
```

And it doesn't change anything from the standard solution, as if it's not taken into account

Now from what I read, this seems to be Tkinter bug on MacOS, and the only solution I found require to hard set dimension for each fonts and UI components or something like that

Is there anything more simple I could try ?

Comment: What fonts does your app use? Do you specify custom fonts or are you using the default fonts? I suspect the simplest solution will be to change the size of the font. You shouldn't have to change the size of any components.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I'm not setting a font just using the default one I guess. Seems I managed to change the font size, I will propose this solution to my user and see if it works

Comment: If you're using default fonts, it's just a couple of lines of code to change them.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes I proposed this to my user and will see if it resolves the issue : ``` default_font = Font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
        default_font.configure(size=FONT_SIZE)
        default_font = Font.nametofont("TkTextFont")
        default_font.configure(size=FONT_SIZE)
        default_font = Font.nametofont("TkFixedFont")
        default_font.configure(size=FONT_SIZE)```

Comment: You were right Bryan, it works, I will post the solution I implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution, as @Bryan Oakley proposed, is juste to change the size of the default fonts on Mac OS.
Now I wanted something user friendly, as I noticed the result on my macbook was also different from the one given by the user.

I chose to use a Scale Tkinter component to allow the user to change the size of the font himself :

EDIT : kept for the sake of the solution, but actually the Scale widget doesn't seem to be compatible with all MacOS version either, as it doesn't appear at all on some of them.

First initialization of the GUI :

```
class GUI():

MACOS_DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE = 7
DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE = 9      

def __init__(self,scriptDir,logger,title) :        
    self.scriptDir = scriptDir
    
    self.window = Tk.Tk()
    self.window.resizable(False,False)        
    self.startFontSize = self.DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE        
    
    if platform.system() == 'Windows' :
        self.window.iconbitmap('bestarcade.ico')
    elif platform.system() == 'Darwin' :
        # Handle tkinter font size bug on MacOS
        self.startFontSize = self.MACOS_DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE
        
    self.setFontSize(self.startFontSize)
    self.window.title(title)        
    self.logger = logger

def draw(self) :
    self.root = Tk.Frame(self.window,padx=10,pady=5)
    self.root.grid(column=0,row=0)
    self.drawSliderFrame()
    self.drawMainframe()
    self.window.mainloop()
```

Then in the same class, creation of the scale component and its event handler (also used during initialization of the GUI) :

```
def setFontSize(self, value) :        
    default_font = Font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
    default_font.configure(size=value)
    text_font = Font.nametofont("TkTextFont")
    text_font.configure(size=value)
    fixed_font = Font.nametofont("TkFixedFont")
    fixed_font.configure(size=value)

def drawSliderFrame(self) :
    self.sliderFrame = Tk.Frame(self.root,padx=10,pady=0)
    self.sliderFrame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="EW",pady=0)
    self.sliderFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.slider = Tk.Scale(self.sliderFrame, from_=4, to=12, orient=Tk.HORIZONTAL, showvalue=0, command=self.setFontSize)
    wckToolTips.register(self.slider, 'Window Size') #TODO internationalization
    self.slider.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="W",pady=0)
    self.slider.set(self.startFontSize)
```

This seems to work well, although it does not resolve all issues around resolution and size of the screen
Size of the windows might have to be reduced at little more than what is done automatically, too

Here it is at default size (9) :
[image]

and here modified with the scale to size 7 :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem!! It would always be a little short, no matter what I tried.

In the end, this is what I did. See if it works for you.

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Whatever you want")

window.focus()

HEIGHT = window.winfo_screenwidth()
WIDTH = window.winfo_screenheight()
RESOL = str(HEIGHT) + "x" + str(WIDTH+7) + "+" + str(-7) + "+" + str(0)
window.geometry(RESOL)
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This just does some kind of fullscreen or I'm mistaken ?

Comment: @Voljega If this helped you, please upvote and accept.

Comment: sorry but it was not the solution I was looking for, I wanted to keep the window as it is displayed, not full screen, just resolve the issue on MacOS. I found a solution with the help of @Bryan Oakley